# Lambda function stops execution open s3Client send command

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get a JSON object from s3 in my lambda function. I tested the code locally and it works fine, in my lambda function it halts the execution immediately when I invoked the s3client.send(command) line. Here is my code:

```
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: process.env.REGION });

console.log("S3 Client Configuration: ", JSON.stringify(s3Client.config));

const getObjectFromS3 = async (bucket, key) => {
  console.log(`Entering getObjectFromS3. Bucket: ${bucket}, Key: ${key}`);
  try {
    console.log(`Creating GetObjectCommand`);
    const command = new GetObjectCommand({
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: key,
    });

    console.log("About to log S3Client configuration");
    console.log("S3 Client Configuration: ", JSON.stringify(s3Client.config));

    let response;
    try {
      console.log("Executing S3Client.send()");
      console.log("Timestamp before S3 send: ", new Date().toISOString());
      response = await s3Client.send(command);
      console.log("Timestamp after S3 send: ", new Date().toISOString());
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("S3Client.send() failed", err);
      throw err;
    }

    console.log("Decoding body from response");
    const body = await new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(
      await streamToPromise(response.Body)
    );

    console.log("Decoded body: ", body);
    return JSON.parse(body);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(
      `Caught an error fetching object from S3 bucket: ${bucket}, key: ${key}`,
      JSON.stringify(error)
    );
    throw error;
  }
};

function streamToPromise(stream) {
  console.log("Entering streamToPromise");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    stream.on("data", (chunk) => {
      console.log("Received a data chunk");
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    stream.on("error", (error) => {
      console.error("Stream error: ", JSON.stringify(error));
      reject(error);
    });
    stream.on("end", () => {
      console.log("Stream ended");
      resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
    });
  });
}
```

Here are the logs:

```
2023-10-03T13:15:21.290Z    d89a668a-8eef-4d10-8653-8bf145a5f282    INFO    Creating GetObjectCommand

2023-10-03T13:15:21.290Z    d89a668a-8eef-4d10-8653-8bf145a5f282    INFO    About to log S3Client configuration

2023-10-03T13:15:21.290Z    d89a668a-8eef-4d10-8653-8bf145a5f282    INFO    S3 Client Configuration:  {
    "apiVersion": "2006-03-01",
    "disableHostPrefix": false,
    "logger": {},
    "serviceId": "S3",
    "signingEscapePath": false,
    "runtime": "node",
    "requestHandler": {
        "metadata": {
            "handlerProtocol": "http/1.1"
        },
        "configProvider": {}
    },
    "tls": true,
    "isCustomEndpoint": false,
    "systemClockOffset": 0,
    "bucketEndpoint": false,
    "forcePathStyle": false,
    "useAccelerateEndpoint": false,
    "eventStreamMarshaller": {
        "universalMarshaller": {
            "eventStreamCodec": {
                "headerMarshaller": {}
            }
        }
    }
}

2023-10-03T13:15:21.290Z    d89a668a-8eef-4d10-8653-8bf145a5f282    INFO    Executing S3Client.send()

2023-10-03T13:15:21.290Z    d89a668a-8eef-4d10-8653-8bf145a5f282    INFO    Timestamp before S3 send:  2023-10-03T13:15:21.290Z

2023-10-03T13:15:21.323Z    d89a668a-8eef-4d10-8653-8bf145a5f282    WARN    {
    "source": "serverlessSdk",
    "type": "WARNING_TYPE_SDK_USER",
    "message": "Serverless SDK Warning: Following trace spans didn't end before end of lambda invocation: aws.sdk.s3.getobject\n",
    "code": "SDK_SPAN_NOT_CLOSED"
}
```

I have checked and verified the following:

- Lambda execution time is 120 seconds
- Bucket and key name is correct
- The catch block is not entered, the lambda execution just halts
- The local role and the lambda role have the same permission (a GetObject policy for this bucket)

Any ideas how to find the cause for the halting of the lambda function when I try to get something from s3?

Comment: Is your Lambda function configured to run in a VPC?

Comment: @MarkB no it is using the default VPC. I am using serverless framework to deploy the entire stack and haven't configured any VPC.

Comment: If it is using the default VPC, then **yes** it is configured to run in a VPC. By _default_ Lambda functions don't run in a VPC at all. So is it actually running in a VPC or not?

Comment: @MarkB okay, I misunderstood VPCs. It is not.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. Weirdly, getting objects from S3 or invoking other Lambda functions is only possible in the main Lambda handler.

TL;DR: Put the S3 or Lambda function call into the main function handler to avoid random function stops.

I first tried putting my get requests from S3 back into the main handler. This "magically" solved the problem and I bumped into another issue: My function would stop executing upon invoking another Lambda.

I then put all invocations into the main handler and basically only kept small utility functions. I then had no more errors popping up.

It is important to mention that the code for invoking the Lambda or getting from S3 was always invoked through Lambda layers. I have a "lambdaClient" layer and an "s3" layer that I attach to my functions that need the boilerplate for invoking other functions or getting from S3.